# make p tag collapsed after 3 rows

Tags: plugins, php, css, advanced-custom-fields, html

I looking for a way to show a read more link underneath my P tag after 3 lines have been displayed so the user can click the read more then it will show the rest of the text (if its paragraphs long)

I currently have this setup in html using this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp But I am not sure how I would integrate this in my ACF Pro text editor(WYSIWYG)

Comment: Where specifically are you trying to add the read more link? On a single Post? On an archive like a Category? Are you trying to modify the Excerpt, or something else? Normally for this type of change you'd apply a filter using `functions.php` or a custom plugin - ACF is unlikely to do what you need.

Comment: Hey, in my post template I have a p tag which I used ACF pro to echo a custom field into it but if the text is more then 3 lines I want to make it collapsible so if the text area is 500 words to doesn't fill the screen

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to set up some custom PHP to parse the field, and if it's over a certain character count, output different HTML to make it collapsible.